# Unable to run build for gitlab-ci using docker on windows server

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to setup CI for dotnet 4.6 project.
I'm using GitLab v8.5.1 with shared runner v1.0.4.

I have installed a Windows Server 2016 CTP 4 that supports docker and have created an image for gitlab ci runner based on the microsoft windowsservercore image.

There is my `.toml`

```
concurrent = 1

[[runners]]
  name = "docker runner 1"
  url = "http://my_server/ci"
  token = "my_token"
  tls-ca-file = ""
  executor = "docker"
  builds_dir="c:\builds"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "windowsservercoregitlab:latest"
    host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
    privileged = false
```

and `.yaml` files

stages:
  - build

```
job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "Test run my build..."
```

When i run a build it fails with log:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.0.4 (014aa8c)
Using Docker executor with image windowsservercoregitlab:latest ...

ERROR: Build failed with: API error (500): hcsshim::ImportLayer - Win32 API call returned error r1=2147942402 err=The system cannot find the file specified. layerId=c1ef764e74b9a93262141455f30229877e80ed9c04b93af6bc73e03568c33790 flavour=1 folder=C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\c1ef764e74b9a93262141455f30229877e80ed9c04b93af6bc73e03568c33790-1950806090
```

Obviously, it trying to create some volume and fails, but i can't understand which volume or how to setup it properly.

How could i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As I recalled from their most [recent Webcast](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/20/webcast-recording-and-slides-introduction-to-ci-in-gitlab/?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiT0RJell6STBOamhtT1RNMSIsInQiOiIyK0QrWWVxaFgwUlloZ1VadzN1eVNKQTA5Rm5yRGxBc0ZhUWV1Q2xtWFNEamtiNExZXC85NFVFcldmWWxyXC9FMnpXN3JTZHlUYThpZEZEQkY2eFYrNkRHRTRLYWJPZzVjUlBDOWx0SlpXYnU4PSJ9). Currently Windows runners only support 'Shell' and dockers are for Linux/Unix systems (Not sure about Mac). With that said, I have no issue using shell executor.